# HTML WebPy multilpe forms

Tags: python, forms, web.py

I have a rather silly question.

I am trying an app and have two forms on it:

Enter a zip code (submit button)
or
Login if you already have a user id. (submit button)

Now in my code (python using `web.py` framework) i have two `def POST(self)` but which one will the first form and the second login form call?

I am super confused. Now my friend tells me html cannot have two different forms.

Here is the code and the form is incomplete - i am just trying to get the methods running well before I start grabbing more data and building a db schema.

```
import web
from web import form

render = web.template.render('templates/')

urls = (
    '/', 'index'
)

myform = form.Form(
    form.Textbox("Zip Code",
                 form.regexp('^\d{5}$', 'Not a zip code'),
                 description='Enter a 5 digit zip code',
                 maxlength = '5'),
)

myloginform = form.Form(
    form.Textbox("Username",
                      form.regexp('^[^<>\s\@]+(\@[^<>\s\@]+(\.[^<>\s\@]+)+)$', 'Invalid username'),
                      description='Enter your username'),
)

class index:
    def __init__(self): ** i still dont know wtf this does.. 
        pass

    def GET(self):
        form = myform()
        myloginform1 = myloginform()
        return render.index(form,myloginform1)

    def POST(self):
        form = myform()
        if not form.validates():
            return render.index(form)
        else:
            return "The zip code you are located is: %s" % (form['Zip Code'].value)

    def POST(self):
        myloginform1 = myloginform()
        if not myloginform1.validates():
            return render.index(myloginform1)
        else:
            return "Welcome %s" % (myloginform1['Username'].value)

class testfunc:
    def GET(self):
        return "Test function returning!"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = web.application(urls, globals())
    app.run()
```

The `index.html` is below

```
$def with (form, myloginform1)

<html>
<head><title>8reps Welcome.. </title></head>
<body>

<h3>Hi</h3>

<p> Lets find some results in your area.. </p>
<form name="main" method="post">
    $if not form.valid: <p class="error">Try again...</p>
    $:form.render()
    <input type="submit" /> </form>

<p> Already registered? Login as a user..</p>
<form name="login" method="post">
    $if not myloginform1.valid: <p class="error">Try again..</p>
    $:myloginform1.render()
    <input type="submit" />Login</form>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

you may have as many forms on the page as you want, the only issue is how you will handle them.

there are 2 options:

1. two separate backends e.g. `/login` and `/zip` to handle POSTs from forms - in the form tag you will need to add `action` attribute to direct POSTs properly
2. single `/index` where you can handle both forms, but then you need to recognize which form was posted, e.g. by presence of some named field (you can use submit input with the same name but different values:

   ```
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Zip" />
   ```

   and for the second form:

   ```
   <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Login" />
   ```

   then you will know which form was posted by checking value of sent "submit" field.

for sure, you can't have 2 methods wit the same name in class definition.

Comment: Thank you Jerzyk ... for the detailed reply.